# tesseract doOCR returns nothing

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

so im trying to use tesseract... and now that ive finally made it working with no exception  , nothing happens!

ive got a bufferd image (and i checked that i really get an image by saving it... and yeha , i am getting an image) and i use the "doOCR" method on it... and nothing happens!

```
Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
    try {
        String captcha = instance.doOCR(image);
        System.out.println(captcha);
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

captcha is empty after this run.

what am i missing here?

~~~ here is an example of a picture im trying to solve
http://37.48.90.31/captcha/1422177531.png

~~~ looks like ive got something here... went debugging it and after few runs in a long loop (inside doOCR) ive got into a page thats supposed to show me "net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelpe"s code... well it says source not found even tho its supposed to be there. changed few sources still nothing. maybe it has something to do with doOCR not doing anything

Comment: Are you trying to run an OCR on a captcha?

Comment: Not a proper captcha ... its like if i will write few digits in paint and save it as image.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: i am using tess4j. 
other external jars that ive got that have something to do with this subject are - 
jai_imageio , jna , commons-io , scrollview.
scrollview ive just got in to see if it helps , i dont think it does anything actually

Comment: ive just found out that tesseract dosent support 64bit.... but after moving everything to another computer (win7 32bit) it still does the same thing.

Comment: It does support 64-bit. Do you have success with the included sample images?

Comment: Just tried, no. it says i might need to download some image package because its an unsupported file type.(extremely odd)

ive added to my question  a link for that "captha" just to show you how simple it is .

Comment: Try to narrow the possible causes. doOCR() can take a file as input instead of a buffered image, try with it.

Comment: i have tried it when i checked that im actually getting the file into the buffered image. saved the image , checked it looks okay and then .doOCR(~savedFile~).
i

Comment: Other PSM (6, 7, 8,...) recognized the image successfully.

Comment: what is psm? (sorry for my ignorance)

Comment: It's page segmentation mode.